# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to get a pop up menu on iPhone.
The main app is using storyboard, but the pop up is a separate xib file that I load:

```
menu = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SimpleMenuController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:menu.view];
```

and I slide it in and out with animation when pressing a button.

that works fine, but I get a problem when I try to press a button inside that pop up menu

I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
 reason: '-[UIViewController PressCategory:]: 
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d3c040'
```

I have connected the button to `PressCategory` function
I have connected the view to the file owner.

What I have noticed is that my `ViewController` is called `SimpleMenuViewController`, that is where the `PressCategory` function is, so of course it will not find the selector. But I don't know what I am doing wrong in connecting in the `xib` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
menu = [[SimpleMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SimpleMenuController" bundle:nil];
```

so that you're instantiating the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PressCategory function in your SimpleMenuViewController?
If yes, then check weather its parameterized or not.

Declare function in .h file like this:

```
-(IBAction)PressCategory:(UIButton *)sender;
```

Define it in .m file like this:

```
-(IBAction)PressCategory:(UIButton *)sender {
     // write your code here
}
```

Comment: While we're here, start your method name with a lowercase.